# SVG editing making Honeycomb 3.0 emulator slow due to more than 100% CPU usage

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building a SVG editor on Honeycomb. I am using html and
javascript apis for editing the SVG. I am displaying the html in a
webview and calling the javascript functions from my native code. I am
taking two svg layers. The lowermost layer contains the actual svg and
the topmost layer is a transparent layer on which I am drawing, thus
giving the effect of an editor. One SVG s is approximately 2.75 MB in
size. As soon as I draw something(straight line, circle etc) it is
taking approx 50 seconds to reflect on my screen. The CPU usage goes
above 100% when I check on LogCat. However when I test this on Google
Chrome desktop browser it is almost instantaneous. Is it because of my
system specs: 2GB RAM, Windows XP, 1.7 GHZ processor? I must also
mention that I am using 256MB as my emulator's RAM. Any attempts to
increase that makes my emulator non-responsive quite often.

Any suggestions how I can optimize CPU usage or make the emulator
respond faster. Are there any recommended system specs for developing
for Honeycomb?Also will the performance be better in the actual device
which has may be higher RAM than I can afford on the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions how I can optimize CPU usage or make the emulator respond faster.

Add more RAM to your device, then bump the device RAM of the emulator to 1GB. That will help a little. You are probably better served investing the money in buying an actual tablet, or testing on an earlier SDK in the emulator.

> Are there any recommended system specs for developing for Honeycomb?

The "recommended system specs" are "own a tablet". Perhaps later this year, the graphics rendering bottleneck will be resolved, based on the work demoed at the 2011 Google I|O conference.

> Also will the performance be better in the actual device which has may be higher RAM than I can afford on the emulator?

Actual hardware will be 10-100x faster, roughly speaking. There is no point in using today's emulator to draw any conclusions about the speed of your application on hardware.